# Must a degree $6$ field extension with Galois group $S_3$ be the splitting field of a cubic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

> Prove (or disprove by example) the following: If $F$ is a field extension of $K$, not necessarily a Galois extension, with $[F:K]=6$ and $\mathrm{Aut}_K F \simeq S_3$, then $F$ must be the splitting field of an irreducible cubic in $K[x]$.

This is a question from a qualifying exam at my university. I think the requirement that the extension be Galois is necessary for this to be true. Like, if $F$ doesn't have to be Galois over $K$, then there must be an example where $F$ isn't a splitting field at all, right? I've yet to come up with such an example though.

Comment: In a separable extension $F:K$, if the degree $[F:K]$ equals the order of the the group $Aut_KF$, then the extension is Galois. This means that "not necessarily a Galois extension" means "not necessarily a *separable* extension".

Comment: @Crostul Yes, but in this example $F/K$ will be Galois.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown   I don't see why that must be

Comment: @MikePierce It's because if $G$ is a finite group of automorphisms of a field $F$, then $F/F^G$ is a Galois extension of degree $|G|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G=\textrm{Aut}_KF\cong S_3$.  Then the fixed field of $G$, $K'$ say,
contains $K$. Moreover, from a standard theorem in Galois theory, $F/K'$
is a Galois extension with degree $|G|=6$ and Galois group $G$.
From the product formula for degrees $K'=K$, so $F/K$ **is** Galois.

Let $L$ be the fixed field of $(1\,2)\in S_3$. Then $|L:K|=3$.
Let $a\in L$, $a\notin K$. Since $3$ is prime, $K(a)$ cannot be an intermediate extension of $L/K$ by the Galois correspondence, so $K(a)=L$ and $a$ is a zero of an irreducible cubic $g$ over $K$. But $\langle(1\,2)\rangle$ is not a normal subgroup of $S_3$, so $L$ cannot contain all the roots of $g$ and so $F$ must be the splitting field of $g$.